# how to find letter a as first and c as penultimate letter in linux

Tags: linux

I have tried this but i'm not sure if it works.
senate, pizza, project, train, pact, palpatineDiscs, ambient, prizes
These are the words.
I tried is that the answer ?

```
ls p*c*;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ls | grep "^p" | grep c.$
```